# Clicking button causes app to crash Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a BMI Calculator and for some reason, whenever I click the button, the app crashes. However, when building the app, it doesn't report any problems. I think there is a problem with the buttonClick method because Android Studio says that it is never used. I want to build the app so that after clicking the button, it will show your BMI in the textview.

Here is my Java File:

```
package com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityExample extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    String display;
    EditText userWeight, userHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        userWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userWeight);
        userHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userHeight);
        display = "Calculator";

    }

    public void buttonClick(View view){

        int weight = Integer.parseInt(userWeight.getText().toString());
        int height = Integer.parseInt(userHeight.getText().toString());

        if(((703*weight)/(height * height))<18.5) {
            textView.setText("Underweight" + ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }
        else if(((703*weight)/(height * height)) <= 24.9) {
            textView.setText("Normal Weight" + ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }
        else if(((703*weight)/(height * height)) <= 29.9)  {
            textView.setText("Overweight"+ ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }
        else {
            textView.setText("Obese"+ ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }



        // BMI Formula [703  * weight (lb)]/[height^2 (in)]
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
}
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp.ActivityExample">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/userWeight"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor"
        android:hint="Enter Weight (pounds)"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/userHeight"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        tools:ignore="TextFields"
        android:hint="Enter Height (inches)"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userWeight"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userHeight"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClick(ActivityExample)"
        android:text="@string/calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat File:

```
 07-19 19:31:20.011 8395-8395/? I/firstandroidap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    07-19 19:31:20.143 8395-8395/? W/firstandroidap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
    07-19 19:31:20.240 8395-8395/? I/firstandroidap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
    07-19 19:31:20.355 8395-8395/? W/firstandroidap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
    07-19 19:31:20.360 8395-8395/? I/chatty: uid=10083(com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp) identical 10 lines
    07-19 19:31:20.360 8395-8395/? W/firstandroidap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
    07-19 19:31:20.385 8395-8395/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
    07-19 19:31:20.506 8395-8395/? W/firstandroidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
        Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
    07-19 19:31:20.605 8395-8395/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
    07-19 19:31:20.682 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
        android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
    07-19 19:31:20.682 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    07-19 19:31:20.682 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
    07-19 19:31:20.683 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
    07-19 19:31:20.683 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
    07-19 19:31:20.702 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeb5de100: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
    07-19 19:31:20.818 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb5de100: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xef57ee20)
    07-19 19:31:20.946 8395-8420/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb5de100: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xef57ee20)
    07-19 19:31:21.032 8395-8395/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3364 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
    07-19 19:31:22.780 8395-8395/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: StudioProfilers agent attached.
    07-19 19:31:22.823 8395-8463/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
    07-19 19:31:22.914 8395-8395/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
    07-19 19:31:22.915 8395-8395/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp W/firstandroidap: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
    07-19 19:31:23.284 8395-8395/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: Memory control stream started.
    07-19 19:31:23.370 8395-8395/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3420 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
    07-19 19:31:23.808 8395-8469/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking disabled.
    07-19 19:31:23.813 8395-8469/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking enabled.
        JNIEnv not attached
    07-19 19:31:23.846 8395-8469/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: Loaded classes: 11041
    07-19 19:31:24.072 8395-8469/com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp V/StudioProfiler: Tracking initialization took: 259509307ns
```

Comment: If app crashes occure, please also provide the exception log from `LogCat`

Comment: Ok, I updated it with the LogCat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml, change this line inside button

```
android:onClick = "buttonClick"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The app works now. I will accept your answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

call

> void buttonClick(View view)

in

> void onClick(View view)

and setOnClickListener like this:

```
package com.example.amitkulkarni.firstandroidapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityExample extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    String display;
    EditText userWeight, userHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        userWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userWeight);
        userHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userHeight);
        display = "Calculator";

    }

    public void buttonClick(View view){

        int weight = Integer.parseInt(userWeight.getText().toString());
        int height = Integer.parseInt(userHeight.getText().toString());

        if(((703*weight)/(height * height))<18.5) {
            textView.setText("Underweight" + ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }
        else if(((703*weight)/(height * height)) <= 24.9) {
            textView.setText("Normal Weight" + ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }
        else if(((703*weight)/(height * height)) <= 29.9)  {
            textView.setText("Overweight"+ ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }
        else {
            textView.setText("Obese"+ ", " + "BMI: " + Integer.toString( (703*weight)/((height * height)) ));
        }



        // BMI Formula [703  * weight (lb)]/[height^2 (in)]
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        buttonClick(view)
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
}
```